# Problemas con los name de los radiobutton en Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

estoy intentando seleccionar una opcion de varios Radiobutton, sin embargo Rails me permite seleccionar todas, es decir si existe una opcion "Si" y otro "No", me permite seleccionar ambas, se bien que para solucionar esto bastaria con cambiarle el name a los radiobutton, sin embargo, al cambiarles el name a uno solo, corrige el problema pero no permite almacenar nada, se muy bien que Rails crea una especie de Array para ubicar la posicion de la opcion es decir, que si hay 2 opciones Rails los posiciona como: `[Si, 1], [No, 2]`, sin embargo no necesito almacenar la posicion de la opcion necesito almacenar el id de la opcion lo cual no hay ningun problema, mi problema basicamente consiste en que me deja seleccionar mas de una opcion en los radiobutton cuando deberia ser una respuesta unica, y si cambios los name a uno unico no me deja almacenar nada, Rails asigna a cada opcion un name similar a esto:

```
name="respondent[answers_attributes][0][answer_options_attributes][1][question_option_id]"
```

En donde asigna los nombres respectivos de los campos, mas la posicion de los mismos, aunq el nombre es similar para todos el cambio de numero de posicion radica su diferencia de nombre, ¿de que forma podria solventar esto?

Manualmente logre solucionar esto sin embargo tuve que validar muchas cosas, de ser este codigo:

```
<%= answer_option.radio_button :question_option_id, question_option.id %>
```

que es lo mismo a esto:

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'respondent[answers_attributes][0][answer_options_attributes][][question_option_id]', question_option.id, answer_option.object.question_option.id %>
```

a validarlo por esto:

```
<% if params[:action] == "edit" %>
  <% if answer_option.object.question_option_id == question_option.id %>
    <%= radio_button_tag 'respondent[answers_attributes][0][answer_options_attributes][][question_option_id]', question_option.id, checked: true %>
    <%= answer_option.label :question_option_id, question_option.title %>
  <% else %>
    <%= radio_button_tag 'respondent[answers_attributes][0][answer_options_attributes][][question_option_id]', question_option.id %>
    <%= answer_option.label :question_option_id, question_option.title %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>  
  <%= radio_button_tag 'respondent[answers_attributes][0][answer_options_attributes][][question_option_id]', question_option.id %>
  <%= answer_option.label :question_option_id, question_option.title %>
<% end %>
```

Con esto logro solucionar el problema eliminando que Rails asigne la posicion de ubicacion al name, y lo almacena, sin embargo tengo problemas para realizar cambios una vez almacenado, por lo que esto deberia ser un caso muy usado y no he hallado soluciones similares al respecto, agradezco inmensamente puedan ayudarme

Answer (score 0):

Aclaremos que el radio button es para seleccionar 1 sola opción de un grupo de opciones; si necesitas seleccionar varias opciones podes armar varios grupos o sino usar el check button con selección multiple.

Para facilitar la tarea en la vista, desde tu controller podrías meter toda la información en una variable colección y dejar al helper de Rails que haga su trabajo. 
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Yo uso así

```
<%= form.collection_radio_buttons(:valor_en_tu_formulario, @coleccion_de_opciones, :valor, :nombre, { }, { class: "estilos"})  %>
```

:valor y :nombre son datos validos (hash) que vienen en esa colección_de_opciones

Answer (score 0):

No sé si estoy entendiendo bien la pregunta, pero igual lo que necesitas es agrupar los radio buttons con tags `fieldset` de HTML.